# Retrieving HttpWebRequest.GetReponse in an ArrayList directly

Tags: .net, vb.net, rest, web-services, httpwebresponse

I have a code :

```
Dim myReq As HttpWebRequest
Dim myResp As HttpWebResponse

myReq = HttpWebRequest.Create("http......")
myReq/Method = "GET"
myReq.ContentType = "application/json'

myResp = myReq.GetResponse
Dim myreader as New System.IO.StreamReader(myResp.GetResponseStream)
Dim  myText As String = myreader.ReadToEnd
```

and I have :
myText = "["string1", "string2", "string3", ...]"

but I need to have an ArrayList in my ListBox like this :

string1
string2
string3
string4

Ok, I can extract with Split(",") but maybe could I recover the data in an ArrayList right away? 
And without "[ and ]"n for a string and without " " for "string1", "string2", "string3" ?

Thanks,
Ela

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have there is a JSON array. You can use the NewtonSoft.Json NuGet package to parse it.

Here is a minimal example of using it:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim myText = "[""string1"", ""string2"", ""string3""]"
        Dim p = JArray.Parse(myText).ToObject(Of String())

        For Each q In p
            Console.WriteLine(q)
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Refs:

- [Parsing JSON Array using
  JArray.Parse](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParseJsonArray.htm)
- [Convert JSON to a
  Type](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ToObjectType.htm)